# Change column using Case When in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query as

```
SELECT  
    EM.EmployeeId, EM.EmployeeName, EM.Email,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(ETM.EmployeeTypeId, 0) = 2 
          THEN EmployeeType 
          ELSE NULL 
    END AS Tester , 
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(ETM.EmployeeTypeId, 0) = 1 
          THEN ETM.EmployeeType 
          ELSE NULL 
    END AS Developer 
FROM            
    EmployeeMaster EM 
LEFT JOIN
    EmployeeTypeMaster ETM ON EM.EmployeeId = ETM.EmployeeId 
                           AND ETM.EmployeeTypeId IN (1, 2)
                               -- 1 is Developer and 2 is Tester    
WHERE 
    EM.EmployeeId = 6
```

The case is that employee with `EmployeeID=6` is tester as well as developer.
So when I execute this query, then there are multiple records of the same employee (which I don't want) rather than in a single row.

The desired output should be:

```
EmployeeId | EmployeeName |  Email          | Tester  |  Developer
-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------+------------
1          |  ABC         |  xyz@xyz.com    | NULL    |  NULL
2          |  MNO         |  mno@mno.com    | Tester  |  NULL
3          |  PQR         |  pqr@pqr.com    | NULL    |  Developer
6          |  XYZ         |  abc@abc.com    | Tester  |  Developer
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are different...

Comment: Sample table data that match the desired output would make this easier to understand.

Comment: This looks like SQL Server so I removed the irrelevant tag. The SELECT clause doesn't affect how many rows are returned.  There's no reason to use `ISNULL(ETM.EmployeeTypeId,0) =2`. If it's null, all checks fail. `ETM.EmployeeTypeId = 2 `is enough.

Comment: If there are many matching rows, you'll get many result rows. `SELECT` doesn't change that. To combine multiple rows into one you need `GROUP BY`. If you want to convert multiple rows to columns you need `PIVOT`.

Comment: There is an un-needed `,` after the second `CASE` statement in your query following the column alias `Developer`. That would cause an error if run.

Answer (score 1):

Check

```sql
SELECT  EM.EmployeeId, 
        EM.EmployeeName, 
        EM.Email,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ETM.EmployeeTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0 
             THEN ETM.EmployeeType 
             END AS Tester , 
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ETM.EmployeeTypeId = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 
             THEN ETM.EmployeeType 
             END AS Developer  
FROM EmployeeMaster EM
JOIN EmployeeTypeMaster ETM ON EM.EmployeeId = ETM.EmployeeId 
                                  AND ETM.EmployeeTypeId IN (1, 2)
WHERE EM.EmployeeId=6
GROUP BY EM.EmployeeId, 
         EM.EmployeeName, 
         EM.Email
```

PS. If this employee have no any needed role then the query will return empty result. If you need the output with both NULLs then use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: This is a good solution. You mistakenly removed the join to `EmployeeTypeMaster` which hosts the `EmployeeTypeId`, though. And `SUM(EmployeeTypeId = 2)` is MySQL specific where true = 1 and false = 0. OP tagged both MySQL and SQL Server, so we don't know which it is. In standard SQL we'd use `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EmployeeTypeId = 2)`, but only few DBMS support the `FILTER` clause, so we'd use a standard SQL workaround there: `COUNT(CASE WHEN EmployeeTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END)` or `SUM(CASE WHEN EmployeeTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner *You mistakenly removed the join to EmployeeTypeMaster which hosts the EmployeeTypeId, though.*  Fixed. *OP tagged both MySQL and SQL Server* I see [sql] only, nevertheless fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    EM.EmployeeId,
    (SELECT EmployeeName FROM EmployeeMaster WHERE EmployeeId = EM.EmployeeId) AS EmployeeName,
    (SELECT Email FROM EmployeeMaster WHERE EmployeeId = EM.EmployeeId) AS Email,
    
     (SELECT case when COUNT(*) > 0 then 'Tester' else  null end as Tester
     FROM EMPLOYEETypeMaster where EmployeeId= EM.EmployeeId AND EmployeeTypeId= 2) as Tester,
     (SELECT case when COUNT(*) > 0 then 'Developer' else  null end as Developer
     FROM EMPLOYEETypeMaster where EmployeeId= EM.EmployeeId AND EmployeeTypeId= 1) as Developer
    
FROM            
    EmployeeMaster EM 
LEFT JOIN
    EmployeeTypeMaster ETM ON EM.EmployeeId = ETM.EmployeeId 
                           AND ETM.EmployeeTypeId IN (1, 2)
                           group by EM.EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT EM.EmployeeId, EM.EmployeeName, EM.Email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ETM.EmployeeTypeId = 2 THEN ETM.EmployeeType 
           END) AS Tester, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ETM.EmployeeTypeId = 1 THEN ETM.EmployeeType 
           END) AS Developer, 
FROM EmployeeMaster EM LEFT JOIN
     EmployeeTypeMaster ETM 
     ON EM.EmployeeId = ETM.EmployeeId AND
        ETM.EmployeeTypeId IN (1, 2)
                               -- 1 is Developer and 2 is Tester
GROUP BY EM.EmployeeId, EM.EmployeeName, EM.Email;
```

Notes:

- If you want one row for a given combination of columns, then think `GROUP BY`.  (There are alternative methods, such as lateral joins so this is not the only solution.)
- `ELSE NULL` in a `CASE` expression is redundant.
- `NULL` values fail comparisons, so there is no need to handle `NULL` values.
- If you are going to have explicit logic for `NULL` values, use the standard methods of either `COALESCE()` or `IS NULL`.  Don't use bespoke functions when standard functions do the same thing.  But, such handling is not needed.
- If you want all employees, I'm not sure why you are filtering the results only for `6`.